# Does Django automatically add tests to my application?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pydev

I'm using Django within [PyDev](http://pydev.org). I started creating tests for my application. I wrote a single test (in tests.py) and issued `python manage.py test my_application`. The output was:

> ran 188 tests in 5.59s

Why did it run 188 tests while I have only one test?

**EDIT:** All the tests passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it runs tests of all the `INSTALLED_APPS`. This may include apps from `django.contrib` or other third party apps that you added. 187 is probably the number of tests that were found for all those apps. Hence 187 + 1 gives the `ran 188 tests`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to check what are all these tests? (from which apps they come, what they check, etc.)

Comment: Maybe something like that: `python manage.py test --verbosity=2`